# Strange behaviour of Try

Tags: php, authentication, try-catch

I was experimenting with `try` `catch` and found some strange behaviour.

The code

```
<?php
$user = "WrongUserName";
$pass = "WrongPassword";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    echo "Success";
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Login Failed";
}
?>
```

This outputs "Login Failed" as expected, but when I delete variables

```
<?php
// Variables for $dbh is missing

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    echo "Success";
}
    catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Login Failed";
}
?>
```

It outputs

> Notice: Undefined variable: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\simpleBD\db.php on
>   line 6
>   Notice: Undefined variable: pass in C:\xampp\htdocs\simpleBD\db.php on line 6 
>   Success

WHY does is output the "Success" instead of "Login Failed"

Comment: Undefined variables are what in compiled languages would be a compile-time error. try-catch generally catches runtime errors. In other words: having undeclared variables is something you can *definitely* avoid and any IDE will help you in doing that. If you need try-catch for compile-time errors, you are doing something very, very wrong

Comment: To put it a bit differently: try-catch can only catch errors happening while the scoped code is running. Undefined variables, however, are something that will cause an error while code is being "read" by the parser, not while it is being executed. In languages like PHP you just don't quite see a difference in those two steps as they happen almost at the same time (not technically accurate, but just to get the main point across)

Comment: Thank you, I assumed it was because of the corrupted code, but wanted to be clear on that.